# C++ Modify the code to print 2D matrix in spiral order starting from center

Tags: c++, matrix, spiral

I have an assignment which is: Print 2D matrix in spiral order starting from top left corner and then starting from center (end point from first assignment will be the starting point).

I have made the traversal from top left corner, no problem, but I can`t modify the code to do the opposite. Any thoughts?

```
for (int n = 0, i = 0, j = 0, rightWall = size - 1, leftWall = 0; n < size * 
size; n++) {
       if ((i == (leftWall + 1)) && (j == leftWall)) {rightWall--; 
leftWall++;} //SHRINK SPIRAL
       if ((j == rightWall) && (i < rightWall)) {i++; continue;} //GO DOWN
       if ((j < rightWall) && (i == leftWall)) {j++; continue;} //GO RIGHT
       if ((i == rightWall) && (j > leftWall)) {j--; continue;} //GO LEFT
       if ((j == leftWall) && (i > leftWall)) {i--; continue;} //GO UP
}
```

Comment: One of possible ways here is to remember all the points (pairs of coords) generated by your code in the array, and than use this array to print your spiral.

Comment: @Ilya No, assignment was exactly as: read initial matrix in two different ways: from left top and then from center point. I believe problem is with placing helper variables - leftW, rightW and modyfing first if block to grow these walls. But I cant figure it out